# How to wait for result of asynchronous web service call in ASP.NET for best performance

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services, iis

In WebForms ASP.NET site (IIS, single app pool), I have call to lengthy web service method referenced in Visual Studio as Service Reference (.NET 4.0). Unfortunately I must wait for information from web service before I can serve page to user. Currently web service is called synchronously so server can’t reuse current thread to process other requests which has performance impact.

Of course  I can generate asynchronous operations for service reference in Visual Studio and call `BeginGetFoo` instead of `GetFoo`, but still I must wait somehow for result from web service.

Here comes question. If I use `AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne` (as below) will it be any better in whole application performance terms from synchronous call I use today?

```
IAsyncResult result = fooSoapClient.BeginGetFoo();
result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
var foo = fooSoapClient.EndGetFoo(result);
```

And of course, if waiting can be done better I am open for suggestions.

Comment: You might want to read the following documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e08f6yc(v=vs.100).aspx as an answer to your questin that subjective.  You have no provided enough information

Comment: For best performance, don't wait, but set up continuations. The code you posted does pretty much the same as a synchronous call.

Comment: @Ramhound - I've read it. What information you need, I will be glad to add it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want to use an Asynchronous Page. See "[Wicked Code: Scalable Apps with Asynchronous Programming in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163463.aspx)", also [Asynchronous Pages in ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163725.aspx), which talks about web services and Asynchronous Tasks with [RegisterAsyncTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.registerasynctask.aspx).

Comment: I can't use `AddOnPreRenderCompleteAsync()` witout heavy refactoring because web service call sits deep in business logic class used in many pages. And `EndEventHandler` can be executed in different thread, which is another refactoring challenge.

Comment: Well you can't do async stuff without surfacing the async operations. The fact that EndEventHandler is executed in different thread should not matter unless for some reason your code uses ThreadStatic fields.

Comment: @John Saunders - is it possible with `AddOnPreRenderCompleteAsync` to call web service 3 times at once and return when these 3 calls are completed?

Comment: Yes. That's what it's for. It doesn't matter whether the async operations are web service calls, database calls, or whatever.

Comment: @JohnSaunders - I understand, but how to do this? When I call web service 3 times I will have 3 IAsyncResults but for `AddOnPreRenderCompleteAsync` I need to have only one. I can chain IAsyncResults but I don't want to chain, I want to begin all 3 calls just at once.

Comment: @JohnSaunders - Thanks. RegisterAsyncTask looks great!

Comment: @JohnSaunders - I've last question. I noticed that code after return from  `ExecuteRegisteredAsyncTasks` call is executed in same thread as code before this call. So I understand that *manually* calling `ExecuteRegisteredAsyncTasks` doesn't free the request-processing thread to service other requests and this method should be only  automatically called to get scaling benefit?

Comment: I don't know. I've never used that. I've never had that situation.

Answer (score 0):

You'd still be hogging the thread. A "safe" option would be to use ASP.NET MVC's async controllers: http://www.aaronstannard.com/post/2011/01/06/asynchonrous-controllers-ASPNET-mvc.aspx

Ideally though, you shouldn't do long running things on a web request. Have a windows service or something process the long running task (that could get kicked off by a web request dropping something on a message queue or putting a task in a database) and poll from the client using ajax or something and then update the user when it's done.

Comment: I know that I can change whole design to avoid this problem, it's easy to say :-)

Comment: Why the Hell would he add MVC to his Web Forms project just to get async behaviour when Web Forms supports asyncrhonous pages (also services and handlers) since before the MVC project was started?

Comment: async pages / handlers would achieve the same result but what such long running tasks shouldn't be done on the request anyway (app pool recycles etc.).

Comment: It depends on how long running the tasks are. If it is acceptable to make the user wait while the page loads then certainly it is acceptable to run these tasks on the request. It is not like the app pool will recycle in the middle of a request.

Comment: Of course it depends. It should be safe as long as ASP.NET knows there are operations pending. If it's a background thread doing it, ASP.NET won't know. This is worth a read:

http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx

Comment: In his case the operation is in the context of a web request. IIS will not recycle a pool before all requests that have started have ended

Phil Haack's blockpost talks about spinning threads in ASP.NET

Answer (score 0):

If refactoring your code is not acceptable so you cannot follow @John Saunders's answer then the only thing you can do is increase the number of threads for the application. This will allow you to scale better but at some point it will have diminishing returns and you will start hurting the performance. What is more if you do not have users waiting on the request queue (i.e. more than 25 simultaneous users per core on your server) you don't need to do anything. Async programming in the web server helps only with scalability but not actual performance for a single user.